# Optionally hiding a property of DataContract in WCF

Tags: wcf, web-services

I have a datacontract called Customer and have 2 OperationContract contracts like CreateCustomer() and UpdateCustomer() which takes Customer as data contract.

Now, i need to hide some of the properties of Customer datacontract in UpdateCustomer(). For example, there is a property called SSN in Customer data contract. This property should be visible in CreateCustomer() and should not be available in UpdateCustomer() for updation. Any idea, how to do it ?

Do we need to have seperate data contract object for both OperationContract?

Thanks in advance!
Bala

Comment: What is the problem of having that propery available there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need two separate classes, one for the `UpdateCustomer` call that contains only those properties that call should see, and another for the `CreateCustomer` call with all of this (this can inherit from the previous class, obviuosly):

```
[DataContract]
public class UpdateCustomerData
{
  ... have the common data properties here in this clas....
}

[DataContract]
public class CreateCustomerData : UpdateCustomerData
{
   [DataMember]
   public string SSN  { get; set; }
   .....
}
```

And then your calls need to take those classes:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
   [OperationContract]
   public int CreateCustomer(CreateCustomerData customer);    

   [OperationContract]
   public int UpdateCustomer(UpdateCustomerData customer);    
}
```